# Laravel - 404 in all static files

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-code-404

In all the static files (css and js) Apache return 404. Then my Laravel looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRH31.png)

I tri too with the command:

```
php artisan serve
```

and the result is the same.

I using PHP 7.2 and Laravel 6.0.4

Answer (score 1):

After installation of fresh `laravel 6` follow these steps-

1. `composer require laravel/ui`
2. `php artisan ui vue --auth`
3. `npm install`
4. `npm run dev`
5. `php artisan serve`

Authentication support is now added with the help of a package. Please read for more [details](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication).